# Есть ли лучший способ для эмуляции пинг в Java?

Tags: jni, java

Есть сервер, который принимет запросы по формате protobuf, клиенты посылают запросы на сервер, сервер должен пингануть устройство в своей локальной сети и отправить обратно на клиент респонс с результатами   выполненной команды Ping. 
Для решения этой проблемы есть 2 варианта, первый основан на `isReachable` но это платформенно зависимый способ и не "аккуратный":

> Java 5 introduced the InetAddress  class for ICMP ping messages however its behavior is highly platform-dependent. On Windows, the isReachable() method uses connection on TCP port 7 (echo) which gives INACCURATE results both in terms of response times and actual availability.

2 способ основан на JNI. Как его лучше сделать существуют ли уже готовые решения в виде библиотек?
Я нашел только [одну реализацию](http://www.veraxsystems.com/en/products/icmplib), но это не совсем подходит, так как это только для виндовс.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://masterbranch.com/icmp-jni-projects).

Я набрал


    linux java icmp jni library

в гугле. Там еще много похожего (multiplatform).

Comment: masterbranch.com - здесь нашел кое что... но мне нужно с apache license использовать

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вам супер-высокая точность? Требование какое? Пользователи хотят просто проверять доступность машин? Или им надо видеть эти миллисекунды обязательно?

Если миллисекунды не нужны, то смело используйте isReachable. На юниксе с нужными привилегиями он использует ICMP как и полагается, а на винде для отладки и простого TCP хватит.

Ну и в крайнем случае вы можете использовать [JPCAP](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/).